# Setting current title and id of button from response obtained from service

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, nsurlsession

I have a viewcontroller having 6 buttons.And I have a service from which I am getting dictionary in array as response:

```
[  
 {"Id":"2","Name":"Alex"},  
 {"Id":"5","Name":"AMark"},  
 {"Id":"1","Name":"Karta"},  
 {"Id":"7","Name":"Juan"},  
 {"Id":"6","Name":"Honky"},  
 {"Id":"3","Name":"Nirauk"},  
 {"Id":"4","Name":"Chinua"}  
]
```

I want to set the button title as the title of my buttons on run time with respective ids but i am not able to understand that how can I use this response to set the current title as name and id as id?

Comment: Can you explain, what exactly you want to display on button?

Comment: I want to display name as current title of button and i want to allot id to each button also

Comment: Okay, your buttons are in `storyboard` or you are creating them programmatically?

Comment: They are in storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I'm giving a quick idea of how to do this.

Create the button initially and add all in an `NSMutableArray`. Set their names as "" just before the request. Once you get the response, Do a loop with button Array. Inside each loop, again do a loop, which checks the `id` with the index of the element and set the title.

```
int numberOfButtons = 6;
CGFloat xPos = 10;
CGFloat yPos = 20;
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfButtons; i++){
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, 100, 40)];
    //Button Styles
    yPos += button.frame.size.height;
    button.tag = i;
    [self.view addSubview:button];

    //Add the button into array
    [mutableArray addObject:button];
}


//Get the response. Once you get the response do this.

NSArray *responseArray = [[NSArray alloc] init]; //This should be the response from the server

for (UIButton *button  in mutableArray) {
    for (NSDictionary *dict in responseArray){
        if ([[dict objectForKey:@"Id"] intValue] == button.tag){
            [button setTitle:[dict objectForKey:@"Name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use predicate to sort the id value in ascending order and set the button Title  with respective ID values.

Comment: @Lovely Added the code. Has not tested this. But sure this will work in this way.

Comment: @Lovely Then you can set the tags to all your buttons previously. and then do the things after getting the response.

Answer (score 0):

Use predicate to sort the id value in ascending order and set the button Title  with respective ID values

simple and easy

```
NSArray *buttons=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:self.button1,self.button2,self.button3,self.button4,self.button5,self.button6, nil];
NSArray *array= @[@{@"Id":@"2",@"Name":@"Alex"},@{@"Id":@"5",@"Name":@"AMark"},@{@"Id":@"1",@"Name":@"Karta"},@{@"Id":@"7",@"Name":@"Juan"},@{@"Id":@"6",@"Name":@"Honky"},@{@"Id":@"3",@"Name":@"Nirauk"},@{@"Id":@"4",@"Name":@"Chinua"}];

   NSSortDescriptor * idDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Id" ascending:YES];
   NSArray * sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:idDescriptor];
   NSArray * sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

  for (int i=0; i< sortedArray.count; i++) {
    [[buttons objectAtIndex:i] setTitle:[[sortedArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[  
 {"Id":"2","Name":"Alex"},  
 {"Id":"5","Name":"AMark"},  
 {"Id":"1","Name":"Karta"},  
 {"Id":"7","Name":"Juan"},  
 {"Id":"6","Name":"Honky"},  
 {"Id":"3","Name":"Nirauk"},  
 {"Id":"4","Name":"Chinua"}  
]
```

This is your web service response. Now you have 6 button.

```
int i =0;

    NSDictionary *dic = // Response of Ids and name;

    // Set all button tag from 0 to 5;
    //Btn1.tag = 0;

    for (UIButton *btn in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if ([btn isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            if (btn.tag == i) {

                NSString *Ids = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];

            if ([[dic valueForKey:@"Id"] isEqual:Ids]) {

            [btn setTitle:[[dic valueForKey:@"Name"]objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
```